# Cannot read property 'getCompilationErrors' of undefined

Tags: server, serverless-framework, next.js

I'm having issues setting up an express server instance on serverless with nextJs. I keep getting a `Cannot read property 'getCompilationErrors' of undefined` when running the server function. It seems to be an issue with app.render.

- When running debug it seems to be coming from within nextJs

Server.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const next = require('next');
const pathMatch = require('path-match');

const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();
const { parse } = require('url');

const server = express();
const route = pathMatch();

server.use('/_next', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '.next')));

server.get('/', (req, res) => app.render(req, res, '/'));

server.get('*', (req, res) => handle(req, res));


module.exports = server;
```

index.js

```js
const sls = require('serverless-http')
const binaryMimeTypes = require('./binaryMimeTypes')

const server = require('./server')

module.exports.server = sls(server, {
    binary: binaryMimeTypes
});
```

Serverless.yml

```
service: ssr-react-next

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  stage: ${self:custom.secrets.NODE_ENV}
  region: us-east-1
  environment: 
    NODE_ENV: ${self:custom.secrets.NODE_ENV}

functions:
  server:
    handler: index.server
    events:
      - http: ANY /
      - http: ANY /{proxy+}

plugins:
  - serverless-apigw-binary
  - serverless-domain-manager

custom:
  secrets: ${file(secrets.json)}
  apigwBinary:
    types:
      - '*/*'
  customDomain:
    domainName: ${self:custom.secrets.DOMAIN}
    basePath: ''
    stage: ${self:custom.secrets.NODE_ENV}
    createRoute53Record: true
    # endpointType: 'regional'
    # if the ACM certificate is created in a region except for `'us-east-1'` you need `endpointType: 'regional'`
```

Comment: For future reference, this question is related to this tutorial: https://dzone.com/articles/a-crash-course-on-serverless-side-rendering-with-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured a way around this, just needed to prepare the app with async

```js
   server.use(async(req, res, next) => {
       await app.prepare();
       next();
   })
```

Comment: This resolved the error but created a new one:

"Error: EROFS: read-only file system, unlink '/var/task/.next/BUILD_ID'"

Comment: This will now be invoked on every request, no?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add this in the server.js so it looks like this?

```
   server.js after server.use('/_next', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '.next')))
   server.use(async(req, res, next) => {
       await app.prepare();
       next();
   })
```